# React Bootstrap Nav style chnage

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I added React Bootstrap Nav for my React js web app and It worked fine. But after a while, my Nav styles change automatically. I didn't do any style change in that Nav

I added this Nav.It was work correctly
[image]

**After while Nav**
[image]

My Nav code

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {Nav} from 'react-bootstrap';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';


class Postselection extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
<Nav variant="tabs" defaultActiveKey="/home">
  <Nav.Item>
    <Nav.Link as={Link} to="./BlogEditor">Writer</Nav.Link>
  </Nav.Item>
  <Nav.Item>
    <Nav.Link as={Link} to="./Bloguploader">Link</Nav.Link>
  </Nav.Item>
  
</Nav>


        )}
}
export default Postselection;
```

Comment: Update to the latest version of bootstrap, it will fix it.

Comment: how i do it? @kenn

Comment: check the version in package.json compare it to the latest version on npm.

Comment: already I have the latest version of react bootstrap